# Simulation of a typical lead-acid battery for "serious game" purpose

Tags: batteries, lead-acid

I'm writing a game/simulation. The context of the game will be a sealed bunker with an environment control issue.

For this, I need a rough simulation of a typical industrial 12 V lead-acid battery:

- Output voltage
- Heat generated by the battery
- Some failure point (eg : max temperature reached, deep discharge)
- The battery can be charged as well: current drawn while charging

I need some confirmation/help on some points:

- In my understanding, the main factor for output voltage is stage "depth of (dis)charge". I'm not quite sure if the temperature and the voltage drop based on current drawn have that much of an influence on output voltage. What do you think?
- The voltage output vs DoD (depth of discharge) seems to be mostly linear until it reaches a tipping point. Then the voltage drop significantly in a "not so linear" way until the battery can be considered fully discharged. Should I just make it 2 linear functions?
- It seems that once it reached the tipping point, the recharge capacity is greatly reduced, or even impossible, correct?

Overall I'm thinking of doing something like this :

- linear voltage drop depending on depth of discharge until 50% DoD
- after 50% DoD: switch to another linear function, declare the battery "damaged" and impossible to recharge
- heat generated depending on current drawn (based on P = I<sup>2</sup>·R, with R being the internal resistance)
- declare the battery "on fire" after reaching a critical temperature
- ignore the voltage drop due to the current draw (I'm not sure yet)
- make the internal resistance constant instead of being dependent on temperature

I haven't considered how to implement recharging yet. Is there anything important I should implement? (e.g. Generate a lot of heat? DoD% over time? Special case of charging while discharging?)

Overall, I'd like to ignore (if possible) unlikely "edge cases" (e.g. extreme environmental temperature). The simulation will be real-time with a 1 s resolution. The simulation could run for many days, or even weeks, but not years. I'll ignore the aging / degradation of performance over time and charge/discharge cycle, but I don't want to ignore too many things.

Am I missing something important?

Comment: "Battery on fire"? So Lithium based battery then as lead/acid just tend to explode.

Comment: @SolarMike then Thanks for the info. I googled some more based on your input and it seems that it generate explosive gas (hydrolyze?) which may lead to additional damage or fire. Overall, the important bit is that "it won't work anymore" and that it may create a fire. for the sim/game purpose I'll stick to "ring the fire alarm in room X".

Comment: for the sim/game purpose, the battery is expected to fail/explode/burn if there is no forced air cooling for a prolonged time. That's why I need the temperature simulation. The context of the game/sim will be a sealed bunker with environment control issue.

Comment: I think [Battery University](https://batteryuniversity.com/) is probably a better place than here for this particular question.

Comment: @Andyaka hooo ! nice ! thank you !

Comment: You can look up "discharge curves" for many *real* batteries (pretend you're going to buy one, then open the datasheet and it probably has the curves drawn on a graph, if not then try a different one). These datasheets typically *don't* tell you how the batteries get worse with age, though. Nor what temperature they catch fire at :)

Comment: If battery heat is any problem at all, then your battery is undersized. Battery heat is wasted power so you can assume most of the energy that's released is released in the load - unless someone short-circuits the battery. Also remember these are big and really heavy - lots of thermal capacity. And you don't discharge them that fast - a 20-hour discharge time could be typical (if it only takes 2 hours, your battery is too small).

Comment: @user253751 it depend. large uninterruptible power supply drain their battery in less than 30mn and wouldn't survive without air cooling (or at least a room with a large air volume). and the "operator" will also be able to (possibly unknowingly) operate battery beyond their normal operating range. I'd love to explain more but large post with a lot of context/explanation tend to be downvoted/closed. search "mc90v" on YouTube for the kind of sim I have in mind.

Comment: @mc90v I suspect the battery compartment of almost any UPS will be fine heat-wise even when discharging in 30 minutes. Warm, maybe (don't know), but not dangerously warm. I would expect the cooling was more for the electronics than the battery.

Comment: i googled a little bit for a "large" battery pack : 40 x 12V battery discharged at 300kW for 15m. 735A x 735A x 50.7mΩ = 27.4kW. This may be expressed as Wh, i.e. 27.4kW x 0.25h = 6.85kWh. it also indicate that manufacturer consider the heat dissipation to be 10x the discharge time because of the large thermal capacity. however, it appears that I can safely ignore the heat at recharge and heat at float charge. as it appears to be negligible compared to discharge heat at high load.